# Querystring has extra character foreign characters.. Maybe Encoding issue? now what?

Tags: c#, regex, json, encoding, non-ascii-characters

It's somewhat of a Hack, but I'm pointing some JSON API to regular asp.net (C#) page and that call is sending a querystring.

When I look at the querystring in my C# code it looks fine, but if I attempt to open a webpage using the string it breaks. If I count the number of characters Its saying 6 or 7 more than what I see.

I've tried removing non-ascii characters as follows with no luck.

```
string whaturl = "http://" + Request.QueryString["what"];
whaturl = Regex.Replace(whaturl, @"[^\u0000+-\u007F]", "");
whaturl = whaturl.Trim();
```

when I look at the string I only see one extra character that looks like a blank.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need use `HttpUtility.URLEncode`.

Comment: perhaps would have helped.  Turned out the url string was being send with an extra character I could not read followed by /getvalue. when I removed the last 8 or so characters all was fine.